# Interpolate/extrapolate a gate charge curve from two different curves

Tags: interpolation

[Gate charge measured data](https://www.sendspace.com/file/jlsg50). I have gate-charge measurement plots and [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) data for two operating points for a power [MOSFET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET).

1. Vds = 60 V, Id = 50 A
2. Vds = 600 V, Id =  8 mA

Can I generate a plot with the operating point, 600 V, Id = 50 A from this curve?

Comment: …and yet, no data for us to study.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, and 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t).

Comment: i've excel data.. how do i attach here?

Comment: You can upload to [sendspace](https://sendspace.com), or (more preferable) convert your file to *.csv and put the resulting text on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com). Then, link to it here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll upload that data here from my flash drive in like 10-15 min.

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/jlsg50

Above is the link for the excel workbook. The first two sheets are the data for 2 different operating points.

Comment: Please edit your post to include that link instead of merely leaving it in comments.

Comment: I have edited the post. It's the link "gate charge measured data"

Answer (score 4):

Based on the information you gave, you definitely can NOT. Especially since this is a highly non-linear device (as you mentioned it is a power MOSFET).

You need first to have a mathematical "model" that describes the `Id`, `Vds`, and gate charge relation in your device. In fact, this model need to be a predictive model, i.e., one that can be extrapolated to inputs outside your measurement set with sufficient confidence. (May be look at spice models or something similar?)

Once you have such a model, you need to *fit* its parameters to the measured data (which I suspect only 2 Id-Vds curves might be too few in this case). Then, use the model to predict whatever you need.

Thus the short answer: without a model, you can not extrapolate the behavior of a non-linear device to arbitrary points away from measurements.

Comment: Guys, relax. @ram Bichoy meant no disrespect with that comment. Some community members remove "Thanks" from the body because the Q & A medium doesn't go well with salutations and expressions of gratitude unlike forums/chatrooms/email. I personally don't think it's all that bad to leave a one word "thanks" in the post but I probably have, over the years, removed it during edits and people here generally tend to respect an editor's decision (unless there are compelling reasons to revert). You could always thank the folks who answer the question using comments.

Comment: And @Bichoy, I suppose "chit chat" could rub people, especially new users who are unfamiliar with the site, the wrong way. So let's try to avoid that :)

Comment: Maybe we can try a bit more help: Bichoy, did you happen to look at the data the OP finally supplied?

Comment: Thank you Toad. thank you for your help. I was little intimidated because i got down-voted for "chit-chat".. I'm pretty sure the goal of any community is not simply to down-vote. I appreciate your help and i have no hard-feelings.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I did, there seem to be a column labeled `Vds` with lots of values in there, not sure how this relates to the `Vds=600` and `Vds=60` in the question, and also there is no notion of `Ids` in the data at all, which just adds to the puzzle ... not sure what is being asked for anymore ...

Comment: Perhaps the `IdOn` in the dataset label is meant for `Ids`?? ... not sure ...

Comment: Well, there you have it; @ram, when I told you to include data, I meant you to include data in a way so that it makes it easy for potential helpers to help you. What you seem to have supplied is not as useful as it's supposed to be; maybe add some formatting and explanatory labels?

Comment: I apologize. Idon = Ids. Also, Vds =600 V and Vds = 60 V.
the reason for many values is that it's a dynamic circuit, so, during turn on- Vds decreases from 600 V/60 V to down and during turn off, it increases from 0 to upwards maximum.

Comment: If you think it's complicated, i'll try my best to answer your questions. If you think you can't solve it, I'll still be thankful for your help! no worries, either way

Comment: @Ram, I understand your description ... but, sorry, I don't have a better answer than the one above. To accomplish what you are trying to do, it will boil down to predicting the behavior of this transistor for the biasing you looking for. Given it is a non-linear system, this might not be possible, unless you know the physics behind it (=model) or you have lots of testing data that can be applied to system identification techniques. 
Either way, if this is truly what is asked for, it is an off-topic here on `Mathematica`.

Comment: OK. If you think so, it's fine. But i'd like to clarify that i'm not asking to make a prediction based on non-linear model. What i'm wanting to do is to approximate a curve on the two edges of the miller plateau. If you notice the plots, all i'm looking to do is just linearly plot an approximate curve from the two curves or their data

Comment: I would suggest that you put all the relevant info from the comments into the question. Optimally you could provide a small dataset in the text. Downloading and importing is much less convenient than having working code out of the box.

Comment: Thank you all  for trying to help me with this. I'm working in excel to do this.